# Full width flex items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a div with horizontal scrolling in which each item width is depend upon its content. Here is demo of my problem: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fezo316/gvnqbju7/5/)

[image]

Here I want the flex items should take full width depend on its content it should not be wrapped. I have provided horizontal scrolling for the same reason even if the width is beyond the page content should be visible in no wrap fashion.

Below is html code for same:

css:

```
.workflow_container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Html code :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="d-flex  flex-nowrap workflow_container">
   <div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex flex-column bd-highlight mb-3">
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 1</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 2</div>
  <div class="p-2 bd-highlight">Flex item 3</div>
</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An initial setting on flex items is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink). This means that flex items can shrink in order to prevent an overflow of the container.

Just disable `flex-shrink`.

Add this to your code:

```
.mb-3 { flex-shrink: 0; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gvnqbju7/6/